# how to identify nearest road with latitude and longitude given in map

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-maps-v2, android-maps

I am developing an android application that perform map matching (route matching) .
I have got small problem.
Whenever i have latitude and longitude of particular location i want to know where is the nearest road from that location  , Also please tell me on how to identify the directions(east,west,north,south)   and how to identify  the U-TURNS on the road